# Can Sevilla Bonobus or Multiviaje cards be used by more than 1 person?

Tags: tickets, public-transport, europe, spain, seville

Can the public transport cards (bonobus or Multiviaje), be used by more than 1 person? (simialr to how it is in Granada) Or is each card restricted to a single person?

Comment: [London](https://tfl.gov.uk/fares/how-to-pay-and-where-to-buy-tickets-and-oyster/pay-as-you-go/oyster-pay-as-you-go) – you can lend somes types of Oyster card, but not share it: "*If you only have pay as you go credit on your Oyster card, you can lend it to someone else. Two people can't use the same contactless or Oyster card for a journey.*"

Comment: Yes, do you mean different people at different times, or multiple persons on the same trip?

Comment: update: yes, 2 people can use the multi trip card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Tussam website https://www.tussam.es/es/condiciones-de-las-tarjetas

(i) there is a schedule of tickets which are personal, Tarjetas Nominativos, to be used by only one person. The Tarjeta multiviaje is not on the list nor is the Tarjeta turística de 1 o 3 días;

(ii) there is also a schedule of tickets which are not, Tarjetas al Portador.  The Tarjeta multiviaje is on the list, but note that one can only use it up to thirty times in quick succession, so a larger group is recommended to use two cards.

Comment: I think you need to check that as it is not exactly how I read the page to which you link.

Comment: @mdewey I have expanded this: if what I say is wrong please tell me explicitly and I will amend or delete.

Comment: Tarjetas turísticas de 1 o 3 días. Tarjeta válida para 1 ó 3 días, sin límite de viajes. Podrá ser usada por un solo usuario por viaje. So it can only be used by one person at a time although you can leand it to someone.

Comment: But it does not say that about the Tarjeta Multiviaje.